# Transform multiple array as per ID and return to tree-structured

Tags: javascript, typescript

Convert the below arrays to a tree-structured JSON Object, I tried many times but not able to understand how to convert.

```js
let firstLevelArr = [
  { id: '1', name: 'India' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Germany' }
];
let secondLevelArr = [
  { id: 's1', parentId: '2', name: 'Bavaria' },
  { id: 's2', parentId: '2', name: 'Berlin' },
  { id: 's3', parentId: '1', name: 'Maharashtra' },
  { id: 's4', parentId: '1', name: 'Tamilnadu' }
];
```

output should be like below

```js
{
  countries: {
    '01': {
      countryName: 'India',
      states: {
        s1: {
          stateName: 'Maharashtra'
        },
        s2: {
          stateName: 'Tamilnadu'
        }
      }
    },
    '02': {
      countryName: 'Germany',
      states: {
        s3: {
          stateName: 'Bavaria'
        },
        s4: {
          stateName: 'Berlin'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with below code, first of all I just want to push 2nd array in 1st array of object respect to the ID.

```
const mergeArrays = (arr1 = [], arr2 = []) => {
   let res = [];
   res = arr1.map(obj => {
      const index = arr2.findIndex(el => el["parentId"] == obj["id"]);
       const filteredArr = arr2.filter((a, i) => a.parentId === obj.id);
      const state = index !== -1 ? filteredArr : [];
      return {
         ...obj,
         ...state
      };
   });
   console.log(res);
   return res;
};
```

Comment: 1. Please format your JSON in a way that is readable. 2. Please include the code you have written so far attempting to solve this issue.

Comment: Please first show some efforts. What is your current code?

Comment: @DBS Added my code, please look into it